# Check if an array element is a sum of two earlier elements using recursion

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I was solving practice questions from a book when I stumbled upon this one :

*Describe a recursive algorithm that will check if an array A of
integers contains an integer A[i] that is the sum of two integers
that appear earlier in A, that is, such that

```
 A[i] = A[j] +A[k] for j,k < i.
```

*

I have been thinking about this for a few hours but haven't been able to come up with a good recursive algorithm.

Comment: You formula allows j and k to be the same element, is that on purpose?

Comment: I just copied the statement as it is from the book. But i guess both should not be same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A recursive solution without any loops (pseudocode):

```
bool check (A, i, j, k)
    if (A[j] + A[k] == A[i])
        return true
    else
        if      (k + 1 < j)      return check (A, i, j, k + 1)
        else if (j + 1 < i)      return check (A, i, j + 1, 0)
        else if (i + 1 < A.size) return check (A, i + 1, 1, 0)
        else                     return false
```

The recursive function is called with `check(A, 2, 1, 0)`. To highlight the main part of the algorithm it does not check if the array initially has more than two elements.

Answer (score 1):

Not very efficient but..

```
search(A, j, k) {
   for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
      if (A[i] == A[j] + A[k]) {
         return i;
      }
   }
   if (k + 1 == A.length) {
      if (j + 1 < A.length) {
         return search(A, j + 1, 0);
      }
      return -1; // not found
   }
   return search (A, j, k + 1);
}
```

Start the search with

```
search(A, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but if you could please describe the function as recursion relation in text, that would make it clearer to me. Also i am wondering that if we pass search(A,0,0) the first time loop on top would check if (A[0] = A[0] + A[0]).Should this be changed?

Answer (score 1):

In python. The first function (search is less efficient O(n<sup>3</sup>)), but it also gives the j and k, the second one is more efficient (O(n<sup>2</sup>)), but only returns i.

```
def search(A, i):
    for j in xrange(i):
        for k in xrange(i):
            if A[i] == (A[j] + A[k]):
                return i, j, k

    if i > 0:
        return search(A, i - 1)

def search2(A, i, sums):
    if A[i] in sums:
        return i

    if i == len(A) - 1:
        return None

    for j in range(i + 1):
        sums.add(A[i] + A[j])
    return search2(A, i + 1, sums)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print search([1, 4, 3], 2)
    print search([1, 3, 4], 2)

    print search2([1, 4, 3], 0, set())
    print search2([1, 3, 4], 0, set())
```

It will print:

```
None
(2, 0, 1)
None
2
```

Answer (score 1):

```java
  /**
   * Describe a recursive algorithm that will check if an array A of integers contains
   * an integer A[i] that is the sum of two integers that appear earlier in A, 
   * that is, such that A[i] = A[j]+A[k] for j,k < i.
   * @param A - array
   * @param i - initial starting index (0)
   * @param j - initival value for j (0)
   * @param k - initial value for k (0)
   * @param n - length of A - 1
   * @return - true if combination of previous 2 elements , false otherwise
   */
  public boolean checkIfPreviousTwo(int[] A, int i, int j, int k, int n){
    if(i >= n) return false;
    if(j < i && k < i){
      if(A[j] + A[k] == A[i]) return true;
      return(
        checkIfPreviousTwo(A, i, j + 1, k, n) ||
        checkIfPreviousTwo(A, i, j, k + 1, n)
      );
    }
    return checkIfPreviousTwo(A, i + 1, j, k, n);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm should be fairly efficient (well, *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*):

```hs
import Data.Set (Set, empty, fromList, member, union)

-- Helper function (which does all the work)
hassum' :: (Ord a, Num a) => Set a -> [a] -> [a] -> Bool
-- Parameters:
--   1. All known sums upto the current element
--   2. The already handles elements
--   3. The not yet checked elements

-- If there are no elements left to check, there is no sum 
hassum' _    _    []     = False
-- Otherwise...
hassum' sums done (x:xs)
   -- Check if the next element is a known sum
   | x `member` sums     = True
   -- Otherwise calculate new possible sums and check the remaining elements
   | otherwise           = hassum' sums' done' xs
       where sums' = sums `union` fromList [x+d | d <- done]
             done' = x:done

-- Main function
hassum :: (Ord a, Num a) => [a] -> Bool
hassum as = hassum' empty [] as
```

I hope you can make sense of it even if you might not know Haskell.

Comment: Thanks but I don't understand haskell so even from the comments i am not able to make out what the function is doing.If you could describe in text it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The Java version, it also return the index of i,j,k.
the running time of the worst case is O(N^2)

=1= using recursion

```
    private static void findSum(Object[] nums, long k, int[] ids/* indexes*/) {
    // walk from both sides towards center
    int l = ids[0];
    int r = ids[1];
    if (l == r) {
        ids[0] = -1;
        ids[1] = -1;
        return;
    }
    int sum = (Integer) nums[l] + (Integer) nums[r];
    if (sum == k) {
        return;
    }
    if (sum < k) {
        ids[0]++;
    } else {
        ids[1]--;
    }
    findSum(nums, k, ids);
}

private static int binarySearchPositionIndexOf(List<Integer> list, int l, int r, int k) {
    int m = (l + r) / 2;
    if (m == l) { // end recursion
        return r;
    }

    int mv = list.get(m);
    if (mv == k) {
        return m;
    }
    if (mv < k) {
        return binarySearchPositionIndexOf(list, m, r, k);
    }
    return binarySearchPositionIndexOf(list, l, m, k);
}

private static void check(List<Integer> data, List<Integer> shadow, int i, int[] ids) {
    if (i == data.size()) {
        ids[0] = -1;
        ids[1] = -1;
        return;
    }
    // sort it in
    int indexAfterSort = -1;
    int v = data.get(i);
    if (v >= data.get(i - 1)) {
        indexAfterSort = i;
    } else if (v <= data.get(0)) {
        indexAfterSort = 0;
    } else if (data.size() == 3) {
        indexAfterSort = i - 1;
    } else {
        indexAfterSort = binarySearchPositionIndexOf(data, 0, i - 1, data.get(i));
    }
    if (indexAfterSort != i) {
        data.add(indexAfterSort, data.remove(i));
        shadow.add(indexAfterSort, shadow.remove(i));
    }
    // find sum
    if (indexAfterSort >= 2) {
        List<Integer> next = data.subList(0, indexAfterSort); //[)
        ids[0] = 0;
        ids[1] = next.size() - 1;
        findSum(next.toArray(), data.get(indexAfterSort), ids);
    }
    // recursion
    if (ids[0] == -1 && ids[1] == -1) {
        check(data, shadow, i + 1, ids);
        return;
    }
    ids[0] = shadow.get(ids[0]);
    ids[1] = shadow.get(ids[1]);
    ids[2] = i;
}

public static int[] check(final int[] array) {
    List shadow = new LinkedList() {{
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            add(i);
        }
    }};

    if (array[0] > array[1]) {
        array[0] ^= array[1];
        array[1] ^= array[0];
        array[0] ^= array[1];

        shadow.add(0, shadow.remove(1));
    }
    int[] resultIndex = new int[3];
    resultIndex[0] = -1;
    resultIndex[1] = -1;
    check(new LinkedList<Integer>() {{
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            add(array[i]);
        }
    }}, shadow, 2, resultIndex);
    return resultIndex;
}
```

Test

```
@Test(timeout = 10L, expected = Test.None.class)
public void test() {
    int[] array = new int[]{4, 10, 15, 2, 7, 1, 20, 25};
    int[] backup = array.clone();
    int[] result =  check(array);
    Assert.assertEquals(backup[result[2]], 25);
    Assert.assertEquals(result[2], 7);

    Assert.assertEquals(backup[result[0]], 10);
    Assert.assertEquals(result[0], 1);

    Assert.assertEquals(backup[result[1]], 15);
    Assert.assertEquals(result[1], 2);

    array = new int[]{4, 10, 15, 2, 7, 1, 10, 125};
    backup = array.clone();
    result =  check(array);

    Assert.assertEquals(result[0], -1);
    Assert.assertEquals(result[1], -1);
}
```

=2= simple one without recurison:

```
// running time n + n^2
// O(n^2)
public static int[] check2(final int[] array) {
    int[] r = new int[3];
    r[0] = -1;
    r[1] = -1;
    r[2] = -1;

    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap(array.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        int v = array[i];
        List<Integer> ids = map.get(v);
        if (ids == null) {
            ids = new LinkedList();
        }
        ids.add(i);
        map.put(v, ids);
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < array.length; k++) {
        int K = array[k];
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            int I = K - array[j];
            if (map.keySet().contains(I)) {
                List<Integer> ids = map.get(I);
                for (int i : ids) {
                    if (i != j) {
                        r[0] = j;
                        r[1] = i;
                        r[2] = k;
                        return r;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```

Test:

```
    int[] array = new int[]{0,8,8};
    int[] result =  check2(array);
    Assert.assertEquals(array[result[2]], 8);
    Assert.assertEquals(result[2], 1);
    Assert.assertEquals(array[result[0]], 0);
    Assert.assertEquals(result[0], 0);
    Assert.assertEquals(array[result[1]], 8);
    Assert.assertEquals(result[1], 1);
```